# Embedding $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ in $\mathbb{P}^{2}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces, elliptic-functions

In the book of Jurgen Jost, Compact Riemann Surface, is written (page 261):

" As Theorem 5.7.1, it can be shown that $z \rightarrow (1,\wp(z),\wp'(z))$ defines an embedding of  $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ in $\mathbb{P}^{2}$. The image of $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ is then (by (5.10.2)) the plane algebraic curve defined by equation $y^{2}=4x^{3}-g_{2}x -g_{3}$."

Where (5.10.2) is:       $\wp'(z)^{2}=4\wp(z)^{3}-g_{2}\wp(z) -g_{3}$.

My question is: why the image of  $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ by the embedding is the algebric curve $y^{2}=4x^{3}-g_{2}x -g_{3}?$

Comment: Because of $(5.10.2)$ exactly.

Comment: I sorry but I did not understand.

Comment: $(\wp(z),\wp'(z))=(x,y)$ together with $(5.10.2)$ is exactly $y^2=4x^3-g_2x-g_3$ - which part is unclear?